# something difficult when using ng-repeat with angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm have two problem when using angular.

I using ng-repeat to show all my item in database , but I want when click in img , go to review page , I have 30 item , but instead write 30 review page , is there another way better than it ? I'm using angular-ui  router

here is my code to show

```
<tr ng-repeat ="data in mydata">
<td>{{data.code}}</td>
<td>{{data.name}}</td>
<td>{{data.price}}</td>
<td> <img ng-src={{data.img}}/>
</tr>
```

I want when click img1 , go to url/code1 , click img2 , go to url/code2

And problem two is admin page

I have form insert item in admin page , but I want when insert success , auto create review page item it . How can i do that.

Pls help me . Thank in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Also, 
please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in html you can use `ui-sref="review({id: itemid})"`

and in angular

```
state('/,{
  url:'yoururl/{review}',

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem:

You need place link to review-page route in each of items:

```
<li ng-repeat="dog in dogs">
  <a ui-sref="review-page({id:dog})">{{ dog }}</a>
</li>
```

look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/21YHCRpsJ4FgPxUrN6tb?p=preview) at "partial-home.list"

Comment: thank to help , but i want when click in img will go to review page(another page) i use ui-router , instead write 30 page , is there another way better , i edited question . Can you give me a suggest